# Retrieve data from table to jquery modal box

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am doing a Point of Sale project in using JSP and i it has a product page where the items are added using a modal form and then it is added to the mysql and it is showed in a data table. I have used [Reveal modal](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) to design my form. This is the [Interface](http://s8.postimage.org/8zwsqrf6d/Capture.jpg) i made.

The add function works just fine and i have the problem in Edit when i click on the edit(Pencil icon) the modal box just loads, how can i get the relevant item details into the modal form with respect of its item code using jsp or javascript.

The code i have used to show the table is as below

```
<tbody>

                            <%Product dbObj = new Product();
                                ResultSet rs = dbObj.captureItem();
                                while (rs.next()) {

                            %>
                            <tr id="">
                                <td><a href="" data-reveal-id="editModal"><i class="icon-pencil" name="btnEdit" style="color:black;"</a></i> | <a href=""><i class="icon-remove" style="color:black;"></i></a></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("itemCode"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("packNo"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("itemName"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("material"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("category"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("size"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("supplierId"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("supplierName"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getDate("purchaseDate"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getInt("quantity"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getDouble("unitPrice"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getDouble("totalPrice"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getDouble("localRate"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getDouble("foreignRate"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getInt("reOrderLevel"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("location"));%></td>
                                <td><% out.print(rs.getString("description"));%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                        </tbody>
```

> Please help me to get the item code to the edit modal box . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have maintained column names in array. Use below code to access item code based on edit click

```
 columns =["itemCode","packNo","itemName","material","category","size"];
 a={};
 $("td a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $(this).parent().nextAll().each(function(index,val){
      a[columns[index]]= $(val).text();
   });
  alert(a.itemCode);
 });
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ulenib/2/edit)

Comment: I tried your demo example with my modal it works but i have a problem i gave the javascript as in the http://jsfiddle.net/xzp6K/ . The modal box loads fine but the item code is not showing. Please Help

Comment: Can you please make demo with your provide javascript in jsbin or fiddle?

Comment: the above comment includes the jsfiddle link which i have stated the code for javascript it even displays the alertbox, but the itemcode doesnt appear in the modal. please help me,

Comment: As per your scenario there is no problem in retrieving data from table. now the problem is in assigning value to textbox. Check is it textbox is dynamically creating or its value is erased? before reveal of model.

Comment: if the problem is with the text box getting erased ? how can i overcome this problem, trying many ways but none worked. how can i make this work ? i am a beginner to this project

Comment: Erased means textbox value is replaced with empty before modal open.
only way to overcome this problem is to debug your project by yourself  :) ...Debug your project from value assign to modal open.

Comment: i did it and i dono what the real problem, with this problem the other functions are on pending, please can you help me personally by any media via mail, skype or anythng ? pleaseeee

Comment: Sorry right now i am busy with company works if possible please make running demo in jsfiddle or jsbin not only java script. i will check.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the jsp values only  while page loading ..

assign values to javascript variables while loading and use them later while editing

ex : while loading the page declare the js global variables  and assign the values.

```
var itemcode=<%= rs.getString("itemCode")%>;
var packNo= '<%= rs.getString("packNo") %>';
var material=<%= rs.getString("material") %>;  etc..
```

then use these values on edit button click .

Comment: @Suresh can i know how to use it using javascript ? can u explain it so that i may catch up. I am new to jsp. please